# Same Google Drive folder, two Operating Systems

Tags: 16.04, windows, windows-10, google-drive

I was wondering if it is possible to use use the same Google Drive folder from both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04? If yes, what client should I use on Ubuntu?

My setup:
120GB SSD with Windows 10 installed
1TB HDD, 800GB shared partition (where I want my Drive folder) and 200GB partition for Ubuntu 16.04.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I use the official client of Google Drive in my Windows 10 desktop, and in my Ubuntu 16.04 laptop I use [insync](https://www.insynchq.com), the other client for linux is that I know [overGrive](https://www.thefanclub.co.za/overgrive). Both can sync selective folders from Drive.

Both clients are paid, but when I was in the trial period of overGrive, insync offered free accounts for a few days, so I'm using it since then

Comment: Can overGrive sync to an NTFS partition?